# Validity of a quantum operation for generalised state erasure

Tags: error-correction, quantum-operation

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1445.pdf) set of notes, pg. 177, the quantum erasure channel (which does nothing to a transmitted state with probability $1-\varepsilon$ and 'erases' it with probability $\varepsilon$) is defined as the operation
$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho)=(1-\varepsilon)\rho+\varepsilon|e\rangle\langle e|
$$
where $|e\rangle$ is a state orthogonal to the entire input Hilbert space (i.e. $\mathcal{E}\,:\,L(\mathcal{H}_{2})\to L(\mathcal{H}_{2}\oplus\text{Span}(|e\rangle)$, where $L(\ldots)$ refers to the space of operators on a Hilbert space). I'm trying to generalise this to the scenario where the input Hilbert space is not necessarily the space of a qubit; rather it's a space with tensor product structure $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_{A}\otimes\mathcal{H}_{\overline{A}}$, and the channel should 'erase' the $\overline{A}$ subsystem with probability $\varepsilon$. My attempt at doing so is the operation
$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho)\stackrel{?}{=}(1-\varepsilon)\rho+\varepsilon\,\text{Tr}_{\overline{A}}(\rho)\oplus|e\rangle\langle e|
$$
I'm unconvinced that this is a valid operation, as the term involving the partial trace $\text{Tr}_{\overline{A}}(\rho)\oplus|e\rangle\langle e|$ seems to have support on a different Hilbert space to the $\rho$ term - specifically, $\rho$ has support on the full space$(\mathcal{H}_{A}\otimes\mathcal{H}_{\overline{A}})\oplus\text{Span}(|e\rangle)$, but the partial trace term is only supported on $\mathcal{H}_{A}\oplus\text{Span}(|e\rangle)$. My question is therefore whether (a) this channel is indeed not allowable and (b) if not, is a channel describing the scenario I'm interested in even possible? It's easy enough to do it in the case where the $\overline{A}$ subsystem is erased *with certainty* (so we can drop the 'error flag' $|e\rangle$ in the output space), in which case the operation looks like
$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho)=\text{Tr}_{\overline{A}}(\rho)
$$
which is easy to work with and clearly valid, but is the above generalisation even possible to describe by a standard quantum operation?